# What is the name of this similarity measure for sets?

Tags: terminology

just a quick question. Suppose I have two sets $A,\,B$. Is there a specific name for the following similarity measure?

$$\operatorname{sim}(A,B) = \frac{|A \cap B|}{\max\{|A|,|B|\}}$$

It is slightly different from the Jaccard coefficient, but I can't find the proper name for this formula.

Comment: This can probably benefit from additional tags. The set theory ones, however, are not amongst them.

Comment: You should enforce $A$ and $B$ to be finite nonempty sets, else the formula is bogus.

Comment: Interesting. Just out of curiosity, what is your motivation for considering that *particular* formula, as opposed to $|A \cap B|/\mbox{[something else]}$?

Comment: This is just a small part inside an algorithm that searches through a large volume of data for frequent patterns. In reality A and B are collections of sets induced by individual items (i.e. A is a collection of all frequent itemsets which form a frequent itemset with an item _a_, and B is a collection of all frequent itemsets which form a frequent itemset with an item _b_).

Comment: I am trying to find to what extent items _a_ and _b_ appear in the same context in the database of transactions, and the context will be more similar, if the overlap between these collections of frequent itemsets were relatively large. Anyway, I'm just interested if someone knows the name of this formula.

Answer (score 0):

This similarity meaure $\frac{|A\cap B|}{\max(|A|,|B|)}$ is called *Braun-Blanquet similarity*, while the variant $\frac{|A\cap B|}{\min(|A|,|B|)}$ is called *Simpson Similarity*, *Overlap Similarity*, *Overlap Coefficient* or *Szymkiewicz–Simpson coefficient*.

Sources:

1. Encyclopedia of Distances by Deza and Deza:  https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-30958-8
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap_coefficient